# Case SLA timer not matching Default SLA Settings

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, service-level-agreement

I have SLA Failure defined as 2 Days in the Service Management in my Dynamics Customer Service Sandbox, however each time I create a case, the case timer starts as 7 days.

Is this a bug in Dynamics 365 or do we need to change some settings for it?

[image: Case SLA Timer vs SLA Settings]

[image: Incorrect timer]

Comment: any followup questions?

Comment: do you think it is considering 30 mins break everyday ? :) only 9 hours a day and then it makes sense

Comment: Could very well be the case, 30mins break for 6 days do account for 3 hrs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to validate all these:

1. Setup the Business hours (Work days/Work hours), and holidays. This will drive the behavior you are seeing. [Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/gonzaloruiz/posts/crm-sla-failure-and-warning-times-not-what-you-would-expect)
2. Setup the SLA/items, if you have multiple SLA - verify it is activated and set as default. [Read more](https://blog.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/colinmaitland/2018/04/25/using-multiple-slas-for-opportunities-in-dynamics-365---5-of-7)
3. And multiple SLA items can be reordered and verify the SLA associated to your case record using [this technique](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/299107/finding-out-which-sla-item-is-attached-to-a-particular-case)
4. Verify the [timer settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-service/add-timer-control-case-form-track-time-against-sla)

Comment: The business hours are affecting this. A 2 day SLA set with 9am-6:30pm Mon-Sat work schedule creates the timer accordingly. However I still see that the timer gives 3 hours more for Resolve KPI counter. Should this be a bug. editing and attaching the screenshot. Thanks